# Plotting Multiple Points on Google Map using VB.net

Tags: google-maps, sql-server, vb.net

I am creating a database application using VB.net and MSSQL 2012. I have retrieved a list of customer from the database and want to plot them on google map. At it stands, I can only plot the first customer. Below is my code. Can someone help me out as this has been killing me for some times now.

```
    Dim lat As String = String.Empty
    Dim lon As String = String.Empty

    Dim queryAddress As New StringBuilder()
    queryAddress.Append("http://maps.google.com/maps?q=")

    For i = 0 To Me.DataGridView1.RowCount - 1
        If Me.DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value <> String.Empty Then
            lat = Me.DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value
            queryAddress.Append(lat + "%2C")
        End If

        If Me.DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value <> String.Empty Then
            lon = Me.DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value
            queryAddress.Append(lon)
        End If
        WebBrowser1.Navigate(queryAddress.ToString())
    Next
```

Comment: How is your geometry stored in MS-SQL 2012?

Comment: I am retrieving geography coordinates as integer (example Decimal Degree --> 6.3434, -10.2324) directly from the database.

Comment: Create a Polygon around the point then intersect the polygon with any points inside it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20653424/sql-geography-point-inside-polygon-not-returning-true-on-stintersect-but-return

Comment: that is not working and display only last record data

Answer (score 2):

I think this will work:

```
Dim queryAddress As New StringBuilder()
    queryAddress.Append("http://maps.google.com/maps?q=")

    For i = 0 To Me.DataGridView1.RowCount - 1
        If Me.DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value <> String.Empty Then
            lat = Me.DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value
            queryAddress.Append(lat + "%2C")
        End If

        If Me.DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value <> String.Empty Then
            lon = Me.DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value
            queryAddress.Append(lon)
        End If
        WebBrowser1.Navigate(queryAddress.ToString())
        i=i+1 
    Next
```